# FineUploader drop area located outside of template?

Tags: drag-and-drop, fine-uploader

Is it possible to re-located the drop area for Fine Uploader to another area?  In particular, I already have an ASP.NET Webforms control that is, in reality, where I want to allow users to drop files, ideally I would like to make one of the divs inside the control be the drop area for Fine-Uploader.

I have tried using jQuery addClass to inject the 'qq-upload-drop-area-selector' class into the div of the control I want to use, but it did not work.  I am unsure if commenting out the original portion of the template that contained the drop area causes no drop area at all?

If there is no easy way to use another controls div area, perhaps you could recommend a way of positioning the drop area over the targeted div after the fact?

This problem is compounded by the fact that jQuery, Fine-Uploader, and the various controls I am using from DevExpress all need time to set themselves up, before everything is rendered and complete on the page.  That of course makes it a little more tricky when trying to hack in a JS DOM element move or overlay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can locate the drop area wherever you like, in fact, you can have as many drop areas as you want.  If you only want one drop area, and want to include it outside of the template container, then simply omit the drop area container from the template, create a drop area container anywhere in the DOM, and pass a reference to the drop area to Fine Uploader via the API using the [`addExtraDropzone` method](http://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/api/methods.html#addExtraDropzone).

Comment: Ahh perfect, the addExtraDropzone part is what I was missing.  (BTW I would attend the JS meetup at Widen this evening, but I forgot about it, and its 3 hours away LOL.  Take it easy.).

Comment: Glad to be of assistance.  

Re The meeting:  Yep, that's a bit far to drive for a meetup that lasts less than 2 hrs.  Mark and I will both be presenting.  You can catch the video of the meeting on YouTube. It's usually posted via a link in the comments of the MadJS group a day or two after the meeting.  http://www.meetup.com/MadisonJS/events/177543662/